# Waiting list time calculation

Tags: c#

Imagine I had a waiting list with the following in the queue

```
Service 1 - 5 minutes
Service 2 - 10 minutes
Service 3 - 5 minutes
Service 4 - 15 minutes
Service 5 - 20 minutes
```

If I have two staff to service these 5 clients in the queue how could I estimate the waiting time for the next person to walk in the store.

Comment: This reminds me of the bin-packing algorithm... except you're filling two bins simultaneously.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "estimate".. You could just sum the wait times and divide by the number of staff..

Comment: I was thinking I could sum the times and divide by number of staff, if that is the best way.

Comment: It's the simplest, won't be the most accurate.

Comment: If it's specifically this example, then you can see how it plays out, can't you? For the first ten minutes server A serves 1 and 3 and B just 2; then A serves 4 becoming free 25 minutes after the start and then B serves 5 becoming free 30 minutes after the start. If you want a more general case then you'd need to know the frequency of the various customers types and probably just divide, yes. I remember my dad used to have software that ran lots of simulations of this kind of thing, though, modelling arrival times and multi-stage processes. (We just played with the visualisations!)

Comment: Sum and divide will not be accurate at all. `S1 - 100 minutes, S2 - 1 minute` means any `S3` will wait for 1 minute, not 50.

Comment: use the average of the *actual* wait time of the previous 3 or 4 items (Service 0, Service -1 and Service -2).

Comment: zerkms, yes that is good example, and why I was wondering if there was some relatively easy algorithm that can be used. Because most of the services will be relatively similar in length, between 5-15 minutes it might be ok to start but having something very accurate would be more impressive.

Comment: How about - you create a priority queue sorted by waiting time (`ASC`). You immediately put 2 elements into it. Then you pop one, accumulate its value. Pop the other, substract the first one from it and put back the result (unless it's 0). Than you pick the next from the waiting queue (or next 2, if the queue is empty), put it into the priority queue and repeat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it's pretty simple - it's the ["W" queue model as described by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/20/queueing-theory-in-action-plus-frogs.aspx).

Set up an array two "staff" members:

```
List<int>[] staff = new [] {new List<int>(), new  List<int>()};
```

define your queue:

```
int[] queue = new int[] {5, 10, 5, 15, 20};
```

Then simulate the processing - each subsequent customer will go to the servicer that is done first:

```
foreach (int i in queue)
{
    List<int> shortest = staff.OrderBy(s=>s.Sum()).First();
    shortest.Add(i);
}
```

The "next" person to come in will have to wait until the first servicer is free, which is the sum of each of the customers served:

```
int nextTime = staff.Min(s=>s.Sum());

Console.WriteLine("The wait time for the next customer is {0} minutes",nextTime);
```

Output:

> The wait time for the next customer is 25 minutes.

Comment: If you're looking to dive into the theory a little further, Little's law is a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law

Comment: Up, Straight forward answer.

Comment: Nice, I will check this out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a not-so-elegant way to do it...

```
private static int GetEstimatedWaitTime(Queue<int> currentQueue, int numServers)
{
    int waitTime = 0;

    // Short-circuit if there are more servers than items in the queue
    if (currentQueue.Count < numServers) return waitTime;

    // Create a copy of the queue so we can dequeue from it
    var remainingItems = new Queue<int>();
    foreach (var item in currentQueue)
    {
        remainingItems.Enqueue(item);
    }

    // Grab an item for each server
    var itemsBeingServiced = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numServers; i++)
    {
        itemsBeingServiced.Add(remainingItems.Dequeue());
    }

    do
    {
        // Get the shortest item left, increment our wait time, and adjust other items
        itemsBeingServiced.Sort();
        var shortestItem = itemsBeingServiced.First();
        waitTime += shortestItem;

        itemsBeingServiced.RemoveAll(item => item == shortestItem);

        for (int i = 0; i < itemsBeingServiced.Count; i++)
        {
            itemsBeingServiced[i] = itemsBeingServiced[i] - shortestItem;
        }

        // Add more items for available servers if there are any
        while (itemsBeingServiced.Count < numServers && remainingItems.Any())
        {
            itemsBeingServiced.Add(remainingItems.Dequeue());
        }

    } while (itemsBeingServiced.Count >= numServers);

    return waitTime;
}
```